# Accessing ngFor local variable outside the context

Tags: angular, local-variables

I'm trying to show a button "loadmore" when the last comment is displayed using the index local variable but by default this variable is scoped to the ngFor directive.

It's possible to expose it outside of the context ?

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index">
    <comment></comment>
</div>

<div *ngIf="comments.length === i"> <!-- The i variable is unknown -->
    <button>Load more comments</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this is angular 2 right?

Comment: @suraj this is it

Comment: ok..just dont club both angularjs and angular2 tags together..Both refer to different versions

Comment: Even comment is unknown outside the loop..

Comment: @suraj thanks for your reply. My bad, I forget the "s" of comment.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the point of the `*ngIf="comments.length === i"`? You would get the desired effect (a button after the list of comments) without any ngIf.

Comment: Yes its an infinite scrolling. And you both right, the ngIf directive here is useless. This is bad example, but sometimes it could be necessary to accessing local variable and i would like know if there is a cleaner way to expose her outside of the context.

Comment: Try finding a valid usecase, and we'll see how to solve it.

Comment: You know how many comments you retrieve from the database ? You also know the amount of comments that an article have ? So, if allComments > showedComments => Load More comments ?

Comment: @mickev Yes, I use an API that accepts two parameters. One of them allows to know the index of beginning (first) and the other makes it possible to know the quantity of comments returned by the API (limit). So for every call I maid, I set "first" as comments length and the "limit" to 2. What I wanted, is displaying a loadmore button after two searches by scrolling. Why ? To allow the user accessing the footer in bottom (if he doesn't want see comments).

Answer (score 1):

Show the "load more" link always under the comments list.

This is the standard way. The link will be visible when user scrolls below the last comment; no need for an *ngIf.

Component HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments">
    <comment></comment>
</div>
<button (click)="loadMoreComments()">Load more comments</button>
```

Component TS:

```
loadMoreComments() {
    let offset = comments.length;
    // Request more comments starting from offset
}
```

**Hybrid scroll**

If you want to combine automatic infinite scrolling and letting the user find the footer, you can do the same as Instagram does on the web. They require you to click the "Load more" once, but after that it gets automatically triggered every time the user scrolls down enough for it to become visible. The footer is reachable before pressing the button the first time.

Example: https://www.instagram.com/soturidesign/